# linearization of minimum function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex, linearization

I need to be advised in linear programming design. I have spent on this issue some time, I have reached my goal partially, but I am blocked by my lack of knowledge in some areas to go further.
Namely, I need to optimize linear function:

$f({x}_1, {x}_2,...,{x}_n) = {c}_1{x}_1+{c}_2{x}_2+...+{c}_n{x}_n$, where ${x}_1, {x}_2,...,x_n \in [0,1]$.

Like you can see, it is ordinary linear function. Not trivial  requirement is that, some of optimal solutions are more preferred than another one. It means, if result of optimization process is:

${x}_1 = 0, {x}_2 = 0.2, {x}_3=0.8, {x}_4 = 0.1$,

such solution is equivalent to more preferred solution:

${x}_1 = 1, {x}_2 = 0.1, {x}_3=0.0, {x}_4 = 0.0$.

It means, I prefer solutions as following.

Let's denote $\\$ ${s} = \sum_1^n{x}_i, s \in [0, s]$, (sum of all ${x}_i$) and $r= mod \ {s}$, (fraction part of $s$) then: $\Biggl\{{{x}_i=1, i\leq k\\{x}_i=r, {i=\lfloor s \rfloor+1}\\{x}_i=0, otherwise}$

Examples:

If $s=2.1$ then ${x}_1=1, {x}_2=1, {x}_3=0.1$ and ${x}_4,...,{x}_n=0$, if $s=3.8$ then ${x}_1=1, {x}_2=1, {x}_3=1, {x}_4=0.8$ and ${x}_5,...,{x}_n=0\\$

I have figured out that such solutions can be forced by involving constraint using minimum function:
${x}_i=min(1, s-\sum_1^{j=i-1}{x}_j)$ (minimum of 1 and sum of all x'es before ${x}_i$) but such constraint is unfortunately not linear. I was trying of trick:
${x}_i=min(1, s-\sum_1^{j=i-1}{x}_j) = \frac12(1+s-\sum_1^{j=i-1}{x}_j)-\frac12|1-s-\sum_1^{j=i-1}{x}_j|$ but modulus function produces disjoint intervals of feasible solutions. Maybe I am not seeing something, but is seems I need help.

ps. I have to use "pure" simplex solver therefore all what I'am using, must be linear and continous or "tricked".

Can anyone help with it?

Comment: sounds like you can just solve $n$ problems, where in each problem you only optimize the fractional value, you fix the first few variables to $1$, the last variables to $0$.

Comment: I suspect you are not really asking the problem you want help with.  In minimizing a linear function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ over a domain $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in [0,1]^n$ the only possibility is to choose $x_i=0$ for variables with positive coefficients and $x_i=1$ for variables with negative coefficients.  Of course this leaves some options where variables have zero coefficients, but you could just as well omit those variables from the problem since they do not affect the value of $f$.

Comment: I totally agree, in practice my task is much more complicated than I described, there are dozens additional constraints which I did not mention, they do not infuence to problem statement. I just did not want to obfuscate description. Anyway, like I mentioned, there is many solutions of objective function but some of them there are more preffered according to the rules shown in description. Therefore, I need to force simplex to receive such preffered over all possible solutions (probably using some tricks using constraints, additional variables etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As @LinAlg says, optimizing over solutions of the "preferred" is basically the same as optimizing in a single variable. So you just need to find optimal solution and then compare it to the best preferred solution. This is true regardless of what your objective function is.

That said, with a linear objective function, you can easily compute the best "preferred" solution since,
$$
f(1,\ldots, 1, r, 0, \ldots, 0)
= rc_k + \sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i
$$

Depending on if you are maximizing or minimizing, and if $c_k$ is positive or negative it is best to just pick $r=0$ or $r=1$ (unless $c_k=0$ in which case you can pick anything).

More generally, since you're optimizing a linear function over a polygon you will always be able to find a solution on one of the vertices. In your case the polygon is just a cube, which makes finding vertices easy. This means you can easily check the signs of $c_i$ to determine an optimal solution, and then see if one of the preferred form exists or not.

Comment: More general terms are *polytope* and *hypercube* for the problem described by OP.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I agree with both of you. Your suggestions are very similar to my first approach which I directed to. But there is worth to mention some details which you notoced as well. Using such approach I have to run simplex n times where n is a number of variables.Variable count in my task is 60 or more. In fact, executing simplex for 1 variable is not time consuming but building all data structures required to run simplex 60 times seems not optimal, especially if I have to do it a few times per second (I am doing it on the fly of some process in software).

Comment: Executing such linear program on the fly for 60 variables takes a few microseconds only, where building of all necessary data structures takes c.a. 80% of it. My model usually is solved in 5-7 pivots of simplex table. Suggested approach results in increasing execution time hundred percents time. Of course, if there is no another solution, I have to deal with it, but maybe someone is able to propose solution to solve this task in "one shot" simplex execution. What do you think,is it possible?